# nginx, how to serve all static files and forward all other traffic to a fastcgi

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

I want to directly serve all existent files (except .php files)

And the rest of ALL requests (not only .php), forward them to a fastcgi server.

I can redirect all .php files to a fastcgi with:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
}
```

And serve other static files with:

```
location / {
}
```

But I want to serve first "all static files that exists and don't end with .php"
And then, serve "all other requests" (not necessary ending with php) to a fastcgi,

Any idea to accomplish it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [try_files](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for that.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;

    // other CGI parameters
}
```

Make sure you're aware of common [pitfalls](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls).

Comment: not working, and I need to discrimine the .php files

Comment: still not working, the index.php works fine, and existent files like .jpg works fine, but the routes which don't match with any existent file, are not forwarding to the fastcgi: 404 Not Found

Comment: seems to be fixed with:         location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

Comment: I wasn't sure if you're using front controller, so tried to make it more generic. updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you! Patience is a virtue :-)